# mounting problems in cygwin

Tags: mount, cygwin

I am facing a problems when i try to convert my linux application to windows using cygwin.

when mounting i followed as per the commands in the help, but seems still something is missing.

```
$ mount -b C:\Morpeus /home/merlin/Morpeus_work/
```

Output:

mount: unknown option -- b

Try `mount --help' for more information.

```
$ mount -o binary C:\Morpeus /home/merlin/Morpeus_work/
```

Output:

mount: /home/merlin/Morpeus_work/: Invalid argument

i try to edit the /etc/fstab, going through the link https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table
but it is read-only, can somebody plz give some examples on how to mount in cygwin.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the output of `mount`

Comment: There is no `-b` option for mount.

Comment: There is an openssl package i have downloaded , in that it is mentioned exactly like that with -b option.

Comment: {shrug}. There is no `-b` option for Cygwin mount

Comment: I don't know Cygwin. In Linux `mount` there is `-B`. In general `-b` and `-B` are not equivalent.

Comment: @DavidPostill, can you please post a valid mount command in cygwin , i have gone through the link, but could not find it, please let me know if i miss something.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mount.html

Comment: Ok, if i use forward slash instead of backward for windows drive it worked.          
 mount -o binary C:/Morpeus /home/merlin/Morpeus_work/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using windows style backward slashes use forward slashes like below, its working.

```
mount -o binary C:/Morpeus /home/merlin/Morpeus_work/
```